# Ajax submissions with jquery in rails not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've been trying to implement a commenting system for my Rails app.  Every event in my app has it's own page, and on the page is a comments thread.  I want users to be able to submit comments using ajax. I have tried to follow RailsCast 136, which is basically what I want to have work in my app.  However, whenever I post a comment, the ajax request is not going through, and I'm receiving the error:

> Started POST "/events/undefined" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-17 00:39:16
>   -0400
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/events/undefined"):

Here's the code for my show action in my events_controller.

```
 def show
 @event = Event.find(params[:id])
 @comment = Comment.new     
 session[:event_id] = @event.id     
 @comments = @event.comments.reverse
 end
```

Here's the code for my comment form in my event show view.

```
<div id="commentform">  <%= form_for(@comment, :remote => true) do |f| %>   

<% if signed_in? %>
<p><%= f.label :author %><br />
<%= f.text_field :author, :value => current_user.name %></p>

<% else %>
<p><%= f.label :author %><br />
<%= f.text_field :author %></p>

<% end %>

       <p><%= f.label :content %><br />
       <%= f.text_field :content %></p>

       <p><%= f.submit %></p>   <% end %> </div>
```

Here's the code for my create action in my comments_controller.

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.create!(params[:comment])
  @comment.event_id = session[:event_id]
  session[:event_id] = nil
  flash[:success] = "Comment sent!"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @comment.event }
    format.js
  end   
  end
```

Here's the jQuery code for posting with ajax.  It is pretty much the same as the code outlined by RailsCast 136

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({  'beforeSend': function(xhr)
{xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")} })

$(document).ready(function(){   $("#commentform").submit(function(){
       $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
       return false;    }) })
```

Anybody have any idea what could be going wrong?  I'm very new to Rails and web development in general and appreciate any help fixing this.

---

**EDIT -:** I managed to fiddle around and fix the problem.  I essentially followed the solution that vinceh laid out in addition to nesting my routes and got it to work.  Thanks guys.

Thanks so much,
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 things right on top.  First you are not specifying where the form is sent to.  So you need to change that to

```
<%= form_for @comment, :url => {:controller => :comments, :action => :create}, :remote => true do |f| %> 

    <% if signed_in? %>

    <%= f.label :author %>
    <%= f.text_field :author, :value => current_user.name %>

    <% else %>

    <%= f.label :author %>
    <%= f.text_field :author %>

    <% end %>

    <p><%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content %></p>

    <p><%= f.submit %></p> 
<% end %>
```

Then you need to add the appropriate route in your `routes.rb` folder, ie

```
match "comments/create" => "comments#create"
```

See if that produces something new.  Let me know and I'll keep updating this answer.

If you want a good comments AJAX tutorial, read [this](http://blog.bernatfarrero.com/jquery-and-rails-3-mini-tutorial/)!

Good luck!

Comment: Hey vinceh,

Thanks a lot for the suggestions.  I added those lines of code but the same error message is showing up in the logs.  I think something is wrong with the way i have coded my create action.  When I click submit, I think it tries to load url /events/undefined, which is causing the error.

Comment: Ok I have a couple more problems now.  First of all, when I submit the form, it continues to process the form with format.html instead of format.js (it gives me the error Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-17 02:51:50 -0400
  Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
).

The other problem is that when comments are created, rails is unable to read the event_id from the sessions hash and is unable to assign my comments an event_id.  Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on vinceh's answer, I'm wondering if you could make things easier on yourself by nesting your resources properly in your routes.rb.  Modify your existing :events route to provide a block, like so:

```
resources :events do
  resources :comments, :only [:create]
end
```

Then, if your form still isn't working, try this:

```
<%= form_for(@comment, :url => event_comments_url(@event), :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

This way, it will automatically pick up the :event_id in the params as part of the post.

Comment: Hey justin,

Thanks for the pointers.  I'm at the point now where the respond_to block is processing the create action as HTML correctly, but executing the format.js as I'd like it to.  I tried commenting out the format.html line, but when I tried to submit, it redirected me to http://0.0.0.0:3000/events/1/comments.  Also, as another note,the respond_to block would not work unless I included it in the if statement if comment.save.  Any ideas?  Thanks again!